# ArcMap graduated colours minimum classification

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I'm plotting point data which I am colouring according to a certain field within the data.
However, the classification which determines the value ranges associated with each colour seems to have a fixed minimum value (in this case of around 0.14), despite there being data points with values much lower than that (~0.04) and so data is being hidden/removed from the map after applying the colour scheme. I'm not sure what this minimum is being based on, but when I try to change it (e.g. using manual classification), I can't make it any lower.

I thought it might be because not all data points are being sampled as it's quite a large dataset, but increasing the sample size doesn't seem to have any impact.

Does anyone know how it's determining this minimum and how I can change it?

I thought I remembered being able to change it manually in the past.

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using, as increasing the sample size is usually the solution to this problem, but you say that did not work for you? I would make the sample size larger than the number of rows in the featureclass.

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm using ArcMap version 10.6.1
Yep I tried setting the sample size to be larger than the number of data points, but nothing happened. Also tried a significantly larger sample size just to be sure. Unless it takes a while to process the change but shows no indication that it is processing?

Is there no way to manually set/override the minimum?